# Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 17--18

Tags: line-breaking, badness, underfull

Throughout my document, I constantly have problems with the text spreading out when there is no real reason for it. I have tried to look up how to solve it but nothing seems to work for me. I am including the code itself and a picture of the result. It can be added that this happens even when the paragraph is not divided between two different pages.

Very grateful for your help!

```latex
The necessary background information collected was regarding \textit{Mobility and the implications of Value of Time}, \textit{Authority documents regarding Stockholm}, \textit{The Swedish Transport Administration}, \textit{Cooperative-Intelligent Transportation Systems} as well as the \textit{Nordic Way} and \textit{C-Roads} initiatives.
```

[image]

Comment: sorry but you are not showing enough info. Make a small but complete example that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! Could you edit your code to begin with your `\documentclass{}` and end with `\end{document}` , a [Minimal Working Example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) please. It makes copy and pasting easier when the code can be compiled and also we do not need to guess what commands or packages you are using.

Comment: Normally, \textit is not unbreakable.  Somewhere you have redefined it to be so.

Comment: please provide an example that shows the problem

Answer (score 2):

[image]

You have to try quite hard to force TeX to make output that bad.

Above the line you see the default setting.

Below the line I disabled hyphenation, requested the paragraph was stretched over one more line than normal, and specified any amount of bad white space stretching would be accepted. This produces output smiliar to the form you showed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\addtolength\oddsidemargin{-4cm}
\addtolength\textwidth{4.5cm}
\begin{document}

The necessary background information collected was regarding
\textit{Mobility and the implications of Value of Time},
\textit{Authority documents regarding Stockholm}, \textit{The Swedish
  Transport Administration}, \textit{Cooperative-Intelligent
  Transportation Systems} as well as the \textit{Nordic Way} and
\textit{C-Roads} initiatives.

\bigskip

\hrule

\bigskip

\hyphenpenalty=10000
\looseness=1
\tolerance=10000
The necessary background information collected was regarding
\textit{Mobility and the implications of Value of Time},
\textit{Authority documents regarding Stockholm}, \textit{The Swedish
  Transport Administration}, \textit{Cooperative-Intelligent
  Transportation Systems} as well as the \textit{Nordic Way} and
\textit{C-Roads} initiatives.

\end{document}
```